# is there a way to create alias of existing key for all models in mongoose express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have 30+ models and now I have to create one alias for **_id to id**

to create an alias ([aliases mongodb](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#aliases) ) I am adding this key to all models

is there any way to create it for existing and new models I will add in future

HINT:- any common model setting are there in mongoose which helps me

REFERENCE:- sails js do this with [sails model setting](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings)

EX in sails

```
 attributes: {
   id: { type: 'number', autoIncrement: true },// here setting for all models
   createdAt: { type: 'number', autoCreatedAt: true },
   updatedAt: { type: 'number', autoUpdatedAt: true },
 }
```